# In a blockset for my 2 year old: "Q" for...?

Tags: letters

This "ABC Block Set" for my 2 year old has mostly recognizable images to represent each letter. For example, `C` is for "crab" and `O` is for octopus. The only one that doesn't make sense is this one for the letter `Q`. What might it stand for?

[image: The Q Block]

Comment: Are we sure this question belongs here? I mean, it's almost the same as [Which word begins with “y” and looks like an axe in this picture?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/395382/20947) on ELU.

Comment: Reminds me of: https://www.amazon.com/Pterodactyl-Worst-Alphabet-Book-Ever/dp/1492674311

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably a

> quahog

That's not a common word where I grew up, but that wasn't anywhere near clam territory.

Comment: Wow! Internet to the rescue! A whole room full of grownups were stumped today!

Answer (score 9):

Could it be a

> [quahog](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/quahog)?

That's all I've got :P